# How to check when a branch is accidentally merged to another branch in Git?

Tags: git, merge

I have `master` branch and `production` branch. They only differ in `config.js` file. The rule is: `master` branch should frequently being merged to `production` branch (for deployment purpose). On the other hand, `production` branch should **NOT** being merged to `master` branch as it would overwrite master branch's `config.js` file.

The thing is that, someone *accidentally* merge `production` branch into `master` branch. Nobody realise until a lot of commits have been made afterwards. And it is even worse as `production` branch and `master` branch is now both pointed to `HEAD`.

So, now `master` branch is the same as `production` branch. I want to check which merge commit fuses those two branches.

How to do this?

Comment: This is going to keep happening until you stop checking in your configuration that is per-host.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
    `git blame config.js`
from your master branch and look for the line which got overwritten. That will give you the hash of the commit which got merged from production

Comment: It only shows the commit made on production branch long time ago before it's merged into master branch.

Comment: try `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all config.js` and it will show where the production branch got merged into the master.

Answer (score 0):

from the master branch, run `git log` passing in the path of the file you want to filter commits of:

```
git log -- config.js
```

That will tell you when commits changed the file `config.js`